# Is it acceptable to remove roof framing members to install a skylight?

Tags: framing, skylight

I want to bring a professional to install a skylight in our bathroom since we have no windows or outdoor light coming into it.

I wanted to install it in the middle of the bathroom. The contractor and I looked in the bathroom and the contractor noticed a drywall screw indicating a framing member in the middle and said they could not put it in the middle of the bathroom but would have to put it more towards the left or right of that member. I'm not sure what type of member it is (updated info indicates it is a truss, not just a joist).

I didn’t like that idea and he said I could put one window on the left and one in the right but not in the center of the bathroom due to this wood.

However, I later found [a video from Lowes](https://youtu.be/etid0oANZXs) about installation of a skylight. You’ll notice at 56 seconds into the video up to 1 minute 5 seconds when they are cutting through the drywall to install this sky light they too ran into framing which might be similar to what I have run into.

On the video they mention to simply remove this piece of wood. As you watch the video you see the installer cut this piece of wood. This is what I thought the contractor could do. Is this right?

Comment: Get another quote there are ways to put the sky light wherever you want as far as price that sounds steep but if it includes finishing the space above the ceiling maybe not but if they gave that quote without looking in the attic and don’t want to put it where you want find another contractor.

Comment: "Studs" are found in walls, while skylights are typically installed in the ceiling/roof. Can you clarify exactly where this "stud" is?

Comment: Framing is complicated. You might have trusses that the contractor doesn't want to touch without engineering drawings (which puts your job into a whole different ballpark, cost-wise). Get a second quote and make sure they look in the attic. Average cost estimates are seldom useful for figuring out actual costs, btw.

Comment: @brhans i guess its a truss maybe?  Im not really handy but its basically wood above the bathroom ceiling where the drywall is screwed into?

Comment: Dealing with a truss roof is an entirely different animal than what the video you linked to details

Comment: I removed all reference to pricing. That's completely off topic because it is locale dependent and can change every couple of weeks. The only way to know if you're getting a good price is to get _several_ quotes. Also, it's noted in some comments below that you've got a trussed roof. You should [edit] that fact into your original question so others will know that, too. Not everyone reads all the comments.

Comment: This question is unanswerable with the information available (inasmuch as a question was actually asked). Protip: Adding question marks to statements doesn't make them questions. :)

Comment: Look into solar tubes. They're surprisingly effective at directing natural light to dark areas and require much less space. I'd consider them a DIY project for a patient, careful person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment, you've got a truss roof, not just simple rafters.

You'll have to find a contractor who has or works with an engineer to redesign your truss system to be able to install the skylight centered in the room. Or, you'll have to hire the engineer yourself, then find a contractor to work to his specs. Expect that this won't be cheap (for whatever *your* definition of "cheap" is).

However, the only way to know what the pricing will be is to get *several* quotes, then go with the one that has the best references at a price you're willing to pay. You can do the same for engineers and builders.

Or, install the skylight off-center and learn to love it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to remove roof rafters for skylights wider than about 15 in. But will be adding framing to the remaining rafters on either side, this will reinforce them. I have two skylights 4 ft. wide , so two roof rafters and two ceiling joists are missing ( new construction , so they were never there). The inspector looked at it and they have not fallen down in 25 years. The framing around the openings reinforces for the missing rafters and joists. I would find a contractor that understands you can remove a roof rafter under these conditions. I added a 32 in. wide skylight in an existing house years ago; Framing between the roof and ceiling reinforced for the missing rafter and joist.

Comment: Eh I found out the reason he cannot remove it is because its nit a rafter. Its a truss.

Comment: If it's a truss, you probably need an engineer to provide a solution that will be strong and durable.

Answer (score 2):

The new skylight will actually need framing around all 4 sides of it, just like a window. As @blacksmith37 notes, that new framing will also be connected to the roof's preexisting framing, as seen in this screencap from a Lowe's installation video: (it's not just removing framing that's in the way, but modifying the framing to properly match the opening and support the skylight.)

[image]